# Overloaded Extraction Operator Cannot Access Member Variables

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have the following header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "product.h"

using namespace std;

class ProductInfo : Product
{
  int UPC;

public:
  ProductInfo() : Product(NULL, 0.0), UPC(0)
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, ProductInfo& pinfo);
};
```

`Product` contains a protected variable `float price`

When I try to change `float price` within my extraction operator, my IDE (CLion) tells me `protected 'Product::price is inaccessible'`

Here is the relevant code in the cpp file:

```
#include "productinfo.h"

istream& operator>>(istream& is, ProductInfo& pinfo)
{
  char info[256];

  if (is.getline(info, 256))
  {
    strtok(info, ",");
    pinfo.UPC = atoi(info);
    pinfo.setName(strtok(NULL, ","));
    pinfo.price = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
  }

  return is;
}
```

Have I done anything wrong or is this an issue with my IDE?

Comment: It says `Product::price is inaccessible`, take heed.

Comment: You are friending the output operator only with `ProductInfo`, not with `Product` which is inherited `private`.

Comment: Please post the definition of `Product`.

Answer (score 0):

`class ProductInfo : Product` means private inheritance; so `ProductInfo` (and its friends) cannot access private or protected members of `Product` by name.

Probably you wanted to use public inheritance:

```
class ProductInfo : public Product
```